# Questions about characters across similar games

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I can't seem to find anything in the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) that prohibits this style of question and it can have a definitive answer and isn't lengthy...but I'm seeing close votes on a [question I asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57659/similar-heroes-champions-to-kennen-from-league-of-legends-in-dota2) (even though no feedback has been left as to why it might be/will be closed)...

Is it too close to "Identify this game"? or is it to open ended in that there could be hundreds of variations perhaps...

Answer (score 11):

Here's a relevant bit of text from Chat.

For the record, I disagree with the voters, and would vote to reopen as soon as it goes through:

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to express both sides of the issue.  I don't think it's a bad, I'm just not sure it shouldn't have been a comment...  Or maybe expressed differently

Answer (score 3):

I personally think the question you have linked is a very good question.

I'm *guessing* the close votes are from people who do not understand how much in common the games have, and are assuming you ask for a character comparison between completely unrelated games - which could be interpreted as a a general comparison between two unrelated games - which could be interpreted as a game recommendation, which is prohibited on this site. But I'm just guessing.

In any case I disagree with those close votes. For the record I have never played any of these games, but I am familiar with their general concepts and their history.

Answer (score 0):

I think asking rec questions within a single game (possibly series) is fine, but cross-game recs can get tricky. Try to use information from the game you are asking about.  Comparing to other games is fine, as long as that other game is not the bulk of the content.

In the case of [this specific question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57659/similar-heroes-champions-to-kennen-from-league-of-legends-in-dota2), I think it would be infinitely better if you described what playstyle you like in DotA and said "In LoL, I liked Kennan" as supplementary information.  Having that as the sole fact is bad.

I guess the best way I could sum up my feelings is:

**Don't *rely* on Game A to ask a question about Game B.**

**Note:** I originally voted to close, but I'll admit I was jumping the gun.  I am not suggesting closing questions that don't fit this admittedly vague standard.  I am simply stating why it doesn't make a good question.

Comment: -1, I really don't see any way in which this is a useful or valid standard. Either an element is valid across both games or it isn't. I agree that providing supplemental details that provide a charecteristic description of the element for which one is seeking an analogue are what will turn a not so great but on topic question into a very good one, but *not every bad (or mediocre) question is inherently an off topic question.* Downvote if you want, but don't close.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - I never said anything about closing...

Comment: Well then. I still disagree, but your downvotes are yours to use as you please, and I encourage you to do so!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Having an entire paragraph about which weapons you liked in Halo and then ending with "What weapons should I use in Call of Duty" is easily a downvotable question.